# difference between 'stackLabels' and 'dataLabels' in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

What is the difference between 'stackLabels' and 'dataLabels' with respect to column graphs and line graphs . Does it make sense to use 'stackLabels' option in both column graphs and line graphs? Does it make sense to use 'dataLabels' in both column graphs and line graphs?

Answer (score 1):

`stackLabels` is documented as placing labels at the top of stacked columns when their sum is positive, and below when negative.  This means you get exactly one label per distinct x-axis value.  `dataLabels` on the other hand will put the labels on the columns themselves, and will not display the sum of stacked columns--only the individual component values.

You can check for yourself by playing around with the jsFiddles:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/yaxis/stacklabels-style/

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/point/datalabels/